# Is there a safe subset of JSON that can be used with all JSON parsers & databases

Tags: database, json, nosql, specifications, datamodel

JSON is still becoming more and more important for exchange of data but the [JSON specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627) is rather lax in some aspects:

> The names within an object SHOULD be unique.
>
> An implementation may set limits on the size of texts that it
> accepts. An implementation may set limits on the maximum depth of
> nesting. An implementation may set limits on the range of numbers. An
> implementation may set limits on the length and character contents of
> strings.

I think that most JSON parsers ignore duplicated object keys and do not distinguish between minus zero (-0) and zero. Most may also restrict numbers to 32bit float or signed integer. Moreover JSON is allowed to contain characters that are not valid Unicode code points (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515597/how-should-escaped-unicode-be-handled-by-json-parsers-and-encoders)). And I bet that may implementations have problems with Unicode characters above the Basic Multilingual Plane (U+0000 through U+FFFF). But is not also the JSON specification, also JSON databases like CouchDB, MongoDB, Persevere/Dojo etc. add restrictions: I doubt you can use object keys like `id`, `_id`, and `$ref` among all JSON stores because they may have special meaning in each system.

This is somehow frustrating: JSON should be easy but the closer you look the more obstacles you find. Is there a common (not too restrict) subset of JSON that can safely be used among *all* parsers and databases or will the NoSQL movement add [more and more extensions](http://bsonspec.org) and special constructs you should not use in your JSON documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, No.

Granted, there are quite a few bugs (MongoDB, for example, gives `String Parse Error` on numbers larger than 64 bit unsingned INT). Some of these are errors, while others are inherent platform limitations - as with any other non-trivial computer system.

But defining a "safe subset" of JSON I generally don't believe to happen. While you can get [JSON schemas](http://json-schema.org/), having everybody - worldwide - agree on do's and dont's is unlikely to happen.

I broad terms, JSON is popular *because* it has no inherent limitations. (As opposed to ex. ASN.1 or XML.)